# Applying a class to list items when they are first rendered sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a list populated by a store, and each item brings in a timestamp. What I would like to do is check each list item, see whether that time has passed or not, and apply a class to the .x-list-item based on the result.

I think it should be in the initialize function of the view but in terms of referencing all the items one by one when they are rendered and adding a class I am a bit stumped. Here is the standard function I'm hoping to test each list item against:

```
var vDate = Date.parse(item);

var today = new Date().getTime();
if(vDate < today)
{
  // in the past, add past class here
} else {
  // in the future, add future class here
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might be trying to do this, I ended up using Ext.query to target each list item when the view was initialised and went from there.

```
Ext.query('.x-list-disclosure', element)[0];
```

The [0] at the end is to target the first element within the query.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to perform such calculations in `itemTpl` using `XTemplate` instance. Also, for perfomance reasons, probably it's better to precalculate class name and put it to the model. Then you'll just use this new property inside your template as `{className}`.

Here is my sample application using class calculations right inside `itemTpl`:

```
// ST 2.2.1 application
Ext.application({
    name: 'Test',
    launch: function() {
        var view,
            i = 0, N = 100,
            data = [],
            style;

        // fill sample array with random data
        while (++i < N + 1) {
            data.push({
                title: 'Title #' + i,
                date: new Date(new Date().getTime() - Math.random() * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
            });
        }

        // append season classes and other styles to the head of html page
        Ext.getHead().createChild({
            tag: 'style',
            type: 'text/css',
            html: ['.x-list .x-list-item.x-list-item-tpl .x-innerhtml {padding: 0;} ',
                   '.container {padding: 12px 15px; margin-right: 15px;} ',
                   '.spring {background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/flameia/xrabbit/128/Folder-Spring-icon.png) right -4px no-repeat; background-size: 60px;} ',
                   '.summer {background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/flameia/xrabbit/128/Folder-Summer-icon.png) right -4px no-repeat; background-size: 60px;} ',
                   '.autumn {background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/flameia/xrabbit/128/Folder-Autumn-icon.png) right -4px no-repeat; background-size: 60px;} ',
                   '.winter {background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/flameia/xrabbit/128/Folder-Winter-icon.png) right -4px no-repeat; background-size: 60px;} ',
                   '.date {font-size: 0.6em; color: #777;}'].join('')
        });

        // construct list view
        view = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
            items: [{
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'Test'
            }],
            fullscreen: true,
            infinite: false,// play with this and look at dom and console output
            itemHeight: 60,
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<div class="container {date:this.getSeason()}">',
                    '<div>{title}</div>',
                    '<div class="date">{date:date("jS F Y")}</div>',
                '</div>', {
                    getSeason: function(date) {
                        var m = date.getMonth(),
                            season;
                        if (m < 2 || m > 10) {
                            season = 'winter'; 
                        } else if (m > 1 && m < 5) {
                            season = 'spring';
                        } else if (m > 4 && m < 8) {
                            season = 'summer';
                        } else {
                            season = 'autumn';
                        }
                        console.log(season);
                        return season;
                    }
                }
            ),
            data: data
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(view);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. This unfortunately applies the class to the data within the list item and not the list item itself, therefore it doesn't accomplish what I'm after. Thanks though.

Comment: For anyone who might be trying to do this, I ended up using Ext.query to target each list item when the view was initialised and went from there.